# How to hash PySpark DataFrame to get a float returned?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have spark dataframe

```
+--------+-----+
|  letter|count|
+--------+-----+
|       a|    2|
|       b|    2|
|       c|    1|
+--------+-----+
```

Then I wanted to find mean. So, I did

```
df = df.groupBy().mean('letter')
```

which give a dataframe

```
+------------------+
|       avg(letter)|
+------------------+
|1.6666666666666667|
+------------------+
```

how can I hash it to get only value 1.6666666666666667 like df["avg(letter)"][0] in Pandas dataframe? Or any workaround to get 1.6666666666666667

Note: I need a float returned. Not a list nor dataframe.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take first:

```
>>> df.groupBy().mean('letter').first()[0]
```